# Find a closed subset of an algebraic group, closed under products, which does not contain $e$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

The accepted answer for [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68726/a-closed-subset-of-an-algebraic-group-which-contains-e-and-is-closed-under-tak) proves the following statement:

> If $S$ is a closed subset of an algebraic group $G$ which contains $e$ and is closed under taking products in $G$, then $S$ is a subgroup.

I'd be interested to see an example of a closed subset of an algebraic group $G$ which is closed under products but does *not* contain $e$.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is not possible, except for empty set. I think the argument used in the question you linked actually doesn't even use the hypothesis that $e\in S$. You can also reason as follows.

Consider a set $S_0$ with the properties you suggest and is nonempty. $\{e\}$ is closed (because Zariski topology is $T_1$), do $S=S_0\cup \{e\}$ is closed (as union of two closed sets), closed under products (clearly) and contains $e$, so by the cited fact it is a subgroup. But that implies that $S_0=S_0^{-1}$, and since it is nonempty and closed under products, $e\in S_0$.

Comment: Your argument seems unnecessarily long. If a non-empty subset is closed under products and becomes a subgroup by adding the identity, then it already had the identity (since it would contain the inverse of some element).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Good point. It also allows us to dodge the dodgy reductio ad absurdum. ;)