# Is a closed, nonempty subset of a (linear) algebraic group $G$ that is closed under taking products a subgroup of $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-groups, zariski-topology

This is a question based on **Exercise 7.6.5** of Humphreys', *"Linear Algebraic Groups"*. For a solution to that particular problem, see:
[A closed subset of an algebraic group which contains $e$ and is closed under taking products is a subgroup of $G$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/68726/104041)

### The Question:

> Is a closed, *nonempty* subset $H$ of a (linear)${}^\dagger$ algebraic group $G$ that is closed under taking products a subgroup of $G$?

### The Details:

The first "closed" is closed under the Zariski topology; the second, closed as the binary operation of $G$ restricted to $H$. The "subgroup" is as a (linear) algebraic group.

### Thoughts:

My guess is that, yes, $H$ would be a subgroup, in the same way that the two-step subgroup test works for abstract groups:

> **Theorem (Two Step Subgroup Test):** Let $S$ be a *nonempty* subset of a group $T$. Then if:
>
> 1. For all $x,y\in S$, $xy\in S$, and
> 2. For all $x\in S$, $x^{-1}\in S$,
>
> then $S\le T$.

My guess is that 2), in the setting of (linear) algebraic groups, is somehow replaced by Zariski closure.

One way to go about proving this is to analyse a proof of the inspiring exercise to see where $e$ is used, and then adjust where possible.

I have tried that with the proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/68726/104041), the same as linked to above. But $e$ is not mentioned.

---

On the other hand, my intuition is trained so far mostly on abstract groups. So I could be wrong.

### Further Context:

I am studying for a postgraduate research degree in linear algebraic groups.

---

Please help :)

---

$\dagger$: Humphreys states that, whenever "algebraic group" is mentioned in his book, he means, "linear algebraic group"; but I'm not sure if linearity is needed here . . .

Comment: The answers to the question you linked show that $xH=H$ for any $x\in H$, which immediately implies that $e\in H$.

Comment: Ah, of course! I did suspect that. Thank you, @EricWofsey. Do you have any ideas about my main question?

Comment: Unless you mean that we could start with the assumption that $H$ is nonempty, @EricWofsey, in which case I don't follow . . .

Comment: Oh, I get it! This question is actually a duplicate of the linked one, pretty much

Comment: I will close it.

Comment: I will not delete this question (unless advised otherwise), because it might come in handy to other users.

Comment: To discuss whether to delete it, see [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63945974#63945974).